# CakePHP: blank page after installation

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I freshly installed CakePHP following these instructions: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html

Everything went fine except when I go to the page: localhost/myCakeProject I get a blank page without errors.

I have already the required PHP version (7) suggested in this psot: [Blank page after installing CakePHP 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28817687/blank-page-after-installing-cakephp-3)

No errors in the console are shown.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Comment: I'd say: take a look into the http servers error log file, that is where you can actually _read_ what the issue is instead having to _guess_.

Comment: @Oldskool there is no error message in the console.

Comment: did you check cakephp's own error log? did you set your debug to true in app.php?

Comment: Please enable **php_openssl** and apache **rewrite_module** then restart your wamp/xamp, hope your problem will be fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have experienced same problems. i run my cakephp app on ubuntu server with apache2 and php7. what i did to solved my problems with

enable mod_rewrite with `sudo a2enmod rewrite`, then make change in

```
/var/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

add this below line **DocumentRoot /var/www/html**

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and for ssl/https i make some change as above

```
/var/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
```

below line

```
<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
         SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
```